# How to write codedeploy appspec file?

Tags: .net, tfs, aws-code-deploy

I'm using windows server instance.. I need to use codedeploy for deployment but I always have a problem with the appspec.yml file

What to write in files source/destination and the hooks sections?

Any Help is really appreciated!

Comment: What's the problem with the appspec.yml file? Are there any logs to track?

Comment: I get this error:
"The overall deployment failed because too many individual instances failed deployment, too few healthy instances are available for deployment, or some instances in your deployment group are experiencing problems
Error code: HEALTH_CONSTRAINTS"
I've been searching about this error but I have no problems with the service role or the EC2 instance so I'm trying to make sure my appspec file is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever, here is an example of an AppSpec file for an in-place deployment to an Amazon Linux, Ubuntu Server, or RHEL instance.

```
version: 0.0
os: linux
files:
  - source: Config/config.txt
    destination: /webapps/Config
  - source: source
    destination: /webapps/myApp
hooks:
  BeforeInstall:
    - location: Scripts/UnzipResourceBundle.sh
    - location: Scripts/UnzipDataBundle.sh
  AfterInstall:
    - location: Scripts/RunResourceTests.sh
      timeout: 180
  ApplicationStart:
    - location: Scripts/RunFunctionalTests.sh
      timeout: 3600
  ValidateService:
    - location: Scripts/MonitorService.sh
      timeout: 3600
      runas: codedeployuser
```

For a Windows Server instance, change os: linux to os: windows. Also, you must fully qualify the destination paths (for example, c:\temp\webapps\Config and c:\temp\webapps\myApp). Do not include the runas element.

More information pleas see [AppSpec File Example](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codedeploy/latest/userguide/reference-appspec-file-example.html) for details.